# What is a simple / elegant way in Rails to process code only if a variable is not a Hash or String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To check what params[:_search] is and make the good transform, I am doing :

```
_search = if params[:_search].is_a?(Hash)
    params[:_search]
  else
    CGI::parse(params[:_search].to_s)
  end
end
```

Recently I monkey path Object and wrote this part of code :

```
class Object
  def transform_unless_kind_of(klass)
    (!self.is_a?(klass) ? yield(self) : self)
  end
end

params[:_search].transform_unless_kind_of(Hash) { |_self| GCI::parse(_self.to_s) }
```

Is there a more elegant/native way to process code only if an object is not a wanted kind ?

Comment: Would you please say more about how you're defining 'elegance'? Do you want fewer lines of code? Ability to reuse in other contexts? Or?

Comment: I just edit my answer. I mean fewer lines of code (like the transform_unless_kind_of method), lisibility (and i'm not sure that transform_unless_kind_of is lisible) and also an code that avoid dummy comparison (for exemple an if is not processed like an unless (see: http://rorbservations.com/post/136816741674/rubys-unless-x-is-processed-differently)).

Answer (score 1):

I think you question should be extended with details '**why** there are different types coming?' and 'is there a way to avoid it?'.

Generally monkey patches should be avoided as they are usually tricky to understand.

Here you need to conditionally modify argument, and easiest and cleanest way to do it is to write a conditional statement. Further improvement depends on how often you'll need to use it in other places, how extendable it should be, etc

To use less lines you can use ternary operator, or line modifiers:

```
_search = params[:_search]
_search = CGI.parse(_search) unless _search.is_a?(Hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to convert if/else structures into early returns. Something like this:

```
def search
  _search = ensure_parsed(params[:search])
  ...
end

private 

def ensure_parsed(search)
  return search if search.is_a?(Hash)

  CGI::parse(search.to_s)
end
```

You can even put `ensure_parsed` in a concern or something, and your controller code will be even cleaner and monkey-patch free.